# If we know X is a Poisson binomial random variable what can we say about mX?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that *X* is sum of *m* independent Bernoulli random variables that are not necessarily identically distributed, and thus it has Poisson binomial distribution. Is *mX* also a Poisson binomial random variable?

Comment: @Cardinal: No, that only works for independent copies. A constant multiple of the same random variable does not obey this.

Comment: @Cardinal: No, it is claiming that $X$ is the sum of $m$ independent Bernoulli's so it's Poisson (which is wrong, it's asymptotically Poisson for small probabilities). But even if it's true then $mX$ is not equal to a sum of $m$ independent copies of $X$.

Comment: @AlexR. Oh Sorry, I didn't read the question well. Thanks

Comment: you might want to [check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location-scale_family) this, it is about when is a distribution stable under scaling, @AlexR. your link links to this post...you meant a different one?

Comment: @AlexR. It's a [Poisson Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution), not a Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Poisson Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) random variable is the count of successes in $n$ independent Bernoulli trials with not-necessarily-identical success parameters, ${\{p_i\}}_n$.   *Don't confuse* this with a Poisson random variable; it's a totally different distribution.

Note: A Binomial distribution is the special case of a Poisson Binomial distribution where *all* individual success parameters for the trials *are* identical.

---

Let's consider a simple case, two success parameters $\{1/3,1/4\}$.

- $P(X=0) = \frac 2 3\frac 3 4 = \frac 1 2 \\ P(X=1) = \frac 1 3\frac 3 4+\frac 2 3\frac 1 4 = \frac 5 {12} \\ P(X=2) = \frac 1 3 \frac 1 4 = \frac 1 {12}$
- $P(2X=0) = \frac 2 3\frac 3 4 = \frac 1 2 \\ P(2X=1) = 0 \\ P(2X=2)=\frac 1 3\frac 3 4+\frac 2 3\frac 1 4 = \frac 5 {12} \\ P(2X=3)=0 \\ P(2X=4) = \frac 1 3 \frac 1 4 = \frac 1 {12}$

In General, if none of the success parameters are zero or one, a Poisson Binomial distribution will have *non-zero* probability for *all* integer value in the support $\{0...n\}$.   Multiplying a Poisson Binomial random value by an integer coefficient will not produce a distribution with this pattern.   Hence $mX$ will not have a Poisson Binomial distribution.

---

On the other hand, if you perform the $n$-trial experiment $m$ times and sum the results, this sum of the sum of successes will be have Poisson Binomial distribution.

Comment: Thank you.  I have another question, X/m will not also be a Poisson binomial random variable, right? and if we want to calculate P(X/m < c), were c is a constant, we can calculate P(X<cm) instead, right?

Comment: @Julie if $m\neq1$ $X/m$ will not have the Poisson Binomial distribution. You can see this by the same reasoning as above: Assume you have $m$ independent Bernoulli RV, so you can have at most $m$ successes, now ask for $P(X/m=m)=P(X=m^2>m)=0$, so you won't have a non-zero probability on $\{0,1,\ldots,m\}$

Comment: @user190080 thanks. I think in this case if we want to have $P(X/m=n)≠ 0$,we should have $P(X=mn)≠ 0$ which means that $mn<=m$ and this is only true for $n=1$.  However, to calculate $P(X/m < c)$, were $c$ is a real number between 0 and 1, we can calculate $P(X<cm)$ instead, right?

Comment: @Julie in general you could do that, yes. But remember, in your case $X$ takes only values in the non-negative integers

Answer (score 1):

If $m$ is an integer greater than  $1$, then $mX$ does not have Poisson binomial distribution. For $\Pr(mX=1)=0$, and if $Y$ has Poisson binomial distribution then $\Pr(Y=1)\ne 0$.

Comment: would you please explain a little more?

Comment: I mean why the first probability is zero and why the second one is not.

Comment: The proof above shows that $mX$ is not Poisson binomial. For $mX$ cannot take on a positive value less than $m$. But if $Y$ is a sum $Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_n$ of independent Bernoulli random variables (not necessarily all with the same probability of success), then with positive probability we can have $Y_1=1$ and the rest of the $Y_i$ equal to $0$. So with positive probability we have $Y=1$.